# Amazon-Redshift: How to get entries that are a week old

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write an Amazon Redshift bash script, that once a week, will email me all of the users created in the last week. I have the rest of the query written out, but I cannot figure out how to add a WHERE clause conditional that works like the MYSQL DATE_SUB(). Example:

```
Select *
from users u
where u.timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Note: I do not want to manually enter the date every week, I am hoping for just a quick command that can work as a solution to this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will work::

```
where u.timestamp > dateadd(day, -7, current_date)
```

Comment: Linking documentation from AWS redshift:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html